# Launch a GNOME session in a Ubuntu machine I'm SSH'd into?

Tags: gnome, xorg, ssh

I'm sshing into my friends machine and I'm wondering how would i launch a GNOME session over SSH? I need to open a web browser on his machine to view something which can only be done from his hostname. What's the easiest way to achieve this via SSH?

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to launch a whole gnome session. If you only want to launch a web browser there, you can do it, try ssh -X ... and launch firefox or other web browser you like.

Answer (score 1):

Another method is to use a local browser and use SSH as a proxy

```
ssh -D 3128 user@hostname
```

And temporary configure your browser to use localhost:3128 as a socks v5 proxy.

Since only the data and not the full rendering needs to go through the line this will also be much quicker.

If you need to do this more often, look for the foxyproxy extension that allows automatic switching based on rules.

Answer (score 0):

try `ssh -X user@hostname`. When you then get the prompt you can just type in `firefox` or any X application on the remote machine and pipe the visual output to your machine.

Comment: The specific command after tunneling in is `gnome-session`. FYI, this will consume some bandwidth. I prefer running individual apps rather than the entire GNOME desktop.

Answer (score 0):

Though I have not done it myself. You can basically run graphical apps through client by tunneling X over ssh.

you need to enable X11Forwarding which resides in your ssh config on server machine. I think its on /etc/ssh/
.i.e
X11Forwarding yes

and login to server with ssh -X user@host